# How do I dequeue a Stylesheet, stored in an 'Assets' folder?

Tags: functions, css, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

How do I dequeue a CSS Stylesheet located in `wp-content > themes > theme-name > assets > css > theme-skin > color.css`?

The outputted code, within the Source Code, is:

`<link rel='stylesheet' id='theme-skin-color-css'  href='https://www.example.com/wp-content/themes/theme-name/assets/css/theme-skin/color.css?ver=4.9.4' type='text/css' media='all' />`

I tried entering the following code, into the `functions.php` file:

```
<?php
function remove_parent_styles(){
    wp_enqueue_style( 'theme-skin-color-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/theme-skin/color.css' );
}
remove_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'remove_parent_styles', 1 );
?>
```

Unfortunately, this has not worked.  It may be worth noting that I am working with a Parent WordPress Theme, where the `functions.php` file is within the Child Theme.

Is anyone able to see where I may have gone wrong or whether it could be that files in the Parent's 'assets' folder cannot be overridden, so to speak, within the Child Theme etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you need to:

1. Hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` with a priority later than the parent theme's. The default is `10` so that's a good assumption. If `11` doesn't work, check the parent theme's source to see which priority it's hooked at.
2. Use `wp_dequeue_style()` to do the dequeueing.

That will look like:

```
function wpse_293836_dequeue_parent_styles(){
    wp_dequeue_style( 'theme-skin-color' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_293836_dequeue_parent_styles', 11 );
```

Note that you only need the handle of the script/style you want to dequeue. The path doesn't matter. The handle should just be `theme-skin-color` as WordPress adds `-css` to the ID.

Comment: Turns out that all I needed to do was ammend `wp_enqueue_style` to `wp_dequeue_style`.  With said changes being made, both my orginal and your suggestion works.  Thanks for pointing this out. :-)

Comment: Your code wouldn't have worked with `remove_action`. It needs to be `add_action`, and you don't need to pass the path to `wp_dequeue_style()`.